# MongoDB populating a field for one user with data from another user

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Here are some example users in my users Collection:

```
{_id: 1, profile: {firstName: Maggie, lastName: May}, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'acctOwner'}}
{_id: 2, profile: {firstName: John,   lastName: Doe}, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'acctOwner'}}
{_id: 3, profile: {firstName: Alton,  lastName: May, acctOwner: 1}, username: AltonMay321, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'subAcct'}}
{_id: 4, profile: {firstName: Mary,   lastName: Doe, acctOwner: 2}, username: MaryDoe123, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'subAcct'}}
```

I want to link these accounts together, the subAcct roles with their corresponding acctOwner. Connecting them both with information from the other, the acctOwners to store the id and username of their respective subAcct, and visa versa I want the subAcct to have the corresponding acctOwner id.

So I want it to end up looking like this:

```
{_id: 1, profile: {firstName: Maggie, lastName: May, subAcct: 3, subUsername: AltonMay321}, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'acctOwner'}}
{_id: 2, profile: {firstName: John,   lastName: Doe, subAcct: 4, subUsername: MaryDoe123}, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'acctOwner'}}
{_id: 3, profile: {firstName: Alton,  lastName: May, acctOwner: 1}, username: AltonMay321, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'subAcct'}}
{_id: 4, profile: {firstName: Mary,   lastName: Doe, acctOwner: 2}, username: MaryDoe123, role: {0: 'user', 1: 'subAcct'}}
```

How can I achieve this type of db manipulation in a script? I'm currently button-mashing using Studio 3T's Intellishell and haven't found any solutions.

EDIT: I am hoping to search on the subAcct user's 'profile.acctOwner' value to match them up, but then I want to populate the acctOwner with information about the subAcct, 'subUsername' and 'subAcct'.

Comment: Is this some kind of schema migration?

Comment: Also, how would you know to relate user(_id:1) to user(_id:3)? Is this information not present in this collection?

Comment: Yep, ultimately this is a schema migration that I am trying to do. @OmriLuzon

Comment: @OmriLuzon, sorry I will update the schema. At this moment the subAcct roles have a field in their profile that is {profile.acctOwner}. I should have mentioned that, That is what I'm wanting to use in my search to connect the two.